# How to fix a dropdown menu that extends past bottom of page

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu styled with css that can have an infinite number of items and levels.  The issue I have after getting it to work is that large lists and multiple levels can cause the list to run off the page either at the bottom or too the right.  Is there a way with css to determine that it has run off the page and then move the list so it remains visible?  I looked at a few examples such as this one:

[How to avoid a vertical dropdown menu to add the vertical scrollbar when at bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466723/how-to-avoid-a-vertical-dropdown-menu-to-add-the-vertical-scrollbar-when-at-bott)

But I couldn't get it to work correctly with the css I had.  That code is available here:
(Note there is a reference to jsfiddle dot net that this editor won't let me post so append the following to the jsfiddle dot net URL /petehelgren/SLyPL/22/

```
nav.medianav ul {
width:300px;
}
nav.medianav ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
nav.medianav li {
list-style: none;
}
nav.medianav ul.top-level {
background:#efefef;
white-space:nowrap;
}
nav.medianav ul.top-level li {
border-bottom: #fff solid;
border-top: #fff solid;
border-width: 1px;
}
nav.medianav a {
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
display:block;
font-size: 16px;
height:25px;
line-height: 25px;
text-indent: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
width:100%;
}
nav.medianav a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color:#fff;
}
nav.medianav li:hover {
background: #fcaf17;
color:#fff;
position: relative;
}
nav.medianav ul.sub-level {
display: none;
}
nav.medianav li:hover > .sub-level {
background: #efefef;
color:#000;
border: #fff solid;
border-width: 1px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
top: 5px;
}
nav.medianav ul.sub-level li {
border: none;
float:left;
width:300px;
}
```

Any suggestion for tweaks to get the menu to display even when it is too long or too nested?

Comment: Here's your fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/petehelgren/SLyPL/22/

Comment: When you say "off the page" you main outside of a container?

Comment: Yes.  Outside the container is accurate.  My hope was a way to get the item position to move back into the container.  You can use the scroll wheel if you have a scroll wheel on your mouse but although the scroll bars appear when the items go beyond the container borders there is no way to scroll to the items without a mouse with a wheel.

Comment: Here is some additional info: I added some JavaScript that will automatically scroll the page when the user moves down the list near the bottom but now the auto-scrolling moves the mouse off the list which, because it is triggered hover, disappears.  You can see that effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/SLyPL/28/ so perhaps I need a list that expands on a click rather than a hover? Javascript won't allow me to control the mouse cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css3 columns, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLyPL/23, older browsers may vary, see: http://caniuse.com/#search=columns

```
ul.sub-level{
-webkit-column-count: 2;  
-webkit-column-gap: 15px; 
-moz-column-count: 2;     
-moz-column-gap: 15px; 
column-count: 2;          
column-gap: 15px; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure that is buying me much (looking at the fiddle).  The list under "Seminar Training Video" has another 15 items that extend beyond the container.  The "Homiletics-Aim 01" at the bottom of the list has 15 items below it that do not display.