# Ability to scrolling thru menu dropdown list in ASPX masterpage

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages

I have created my first master page so bear with me if this is a dumb question.  One of my menu drop down lists within the master page is longer than the viewable page, so some of the items in the drop down list are cut off at the bottom of the page.  How can I make the drop down list have the ability to scroll through it so I can see the entire list.

```
nav{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
nav ul{
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
 }
nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;

}
nav a:hover{
    background-color:white;
    color:gray;
}nav ul ul{
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     width:450px;
     top:26px;
 }
 nav ul li:hover>ul{
     display:inherit;
 }
 nav ul ul li{
     float:none;
     display:list-item;
     position:relative;
     background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);     
 }
 nav ul ul ul li{
     position:relative;
     left:450px;
     top:-26px;
 }
 .toggle, [id^=drop]{
     display:none;
 }
 @media all and (max-width:600px){
     .menu{
         display:none;
     }
     .toggle{
         display:block;
         color:white;
         background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
         text-decoration:none;
         padding:20px;
     }
     .toggle:hover{
         background-color:white;
         color:dimgray;
     }
     #logo{
         display:block;
         float:none;
     }
     [id^=drop]:checked+ul{
         display:block;
 }
     nav ul li{
         display:block;
         width:100%
     }
     nav ul ul{
         float:none;
         position:static;
     }
     nav ul ul ul{
         float:none;
         position:absolute;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  To have a scroll bar in the sub menu drop list I needed to add nav ul ul ul and alter the nav ul ul ul li see below;

````
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

    nav ul {
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;

    }

        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }

    nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 15px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

        nav a:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: gray;
        }

    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        top: 26px;

    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: inherit;
    }

    nav ul ul li {
        float: none;
        display: list-item;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }


    nav ul ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        top: 0px;
        max-height: 1000%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    nav ul ul ul li {
        float: none;
        display: list-item;
        position: relative;

    }


.toggle, [id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .toggle {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 20px;
    }

        .toggle:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: dimgray;
        }

    #logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%
    }

    nav ul ul {
        float: none;
        position: static;
    }

        nav ul ul ul {
            float: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set via CSS a maximum height of the container (max-height : number [%, PX, VH] ) of dropdown and specify an overflow / scrolling (overflow-y : [ scroll|auto ] )to get to the bottom of the items. For example:

.nav ul { max-height:100%; overflow-y: auto; }

You can adjust Max-Height with %, PX, VH .. or whatever suites your specific project's use case.

Another option could be to introduce Columns in the dropdown as described here:

[How to fix a dropdown menu that extends past bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012249/how-to-fix-a-dropdown-menu-that-extends-past-bottom-of-page)

Comment: I have my css like this and it didn't change.  I still cannot scroll thru the list: }

`}

    nav ul {
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }`

Comment: Its the line of code where the nav ul ul ul li is that I need to add the scroll bar.  I tried adding the overflow: auto; in that section but it didn't help.

Comment: If you want it on a nav ul ul ul li  then you would add the CSS ..for that level.. 

nav ul ul ul li { max-height: 100%; overflow-y:auto; } 

Now the issue maybe that you since you are at multiple level deep .. you may already be down the page a bit so the height 100% maybe too tall .. try height 20% just to see if it works and move up.  Since this is CSS is will be  scrollbar on the LI itself.. so depending on device may just have to slide up or down to see if content slides..

Comment: I place your recommendation in the ul ul ul il and it didn't change anything `    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        top: 26px;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: inherit;
    }

    nav ul ul li {
        float: none;
        display: list-item;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }


    nav ul ul ul li {
        position: relative;
        left: 300px;
        top: -26px;
        max-height:100%; overflow: auto;
    }`

Comment: As a test I put your recommendation in the nav ul ul section and it works for that column, just not for the column associated with ul ul ul li.

Comment: It it isn't working down at that level then quite possibly there is some overriding style that is not allowing the height to be applied.  I would recommend using your the Web Developer console to see what styles are or are not being applied to the section is isn't behaving.  You could try applying an !important tag to the height to see if it applies at that point .. something along the lines  :  { height :xxx  !important; }